# Retrieve the conversations with latest mesaage, node js, socket io, mysql chat application

Tags: mysql, node.js, sockets, ionic-framework, chat

I am relatively new in building chat application. Ionic, node js, socket io, mysql stack is used for building chat application for both one to one and group chat. The tables in the corresponding db schema is shown below

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The conversation and its id is considered as thread in this design.

When a new message is inserted by the sender in a group:
   The table 'messenger_threads' is populated with the new thread id(group id if it is a group message) and the subject if that group id entry is new, else nothing is inserted.
When a new message is inserted by the sender in the private chat:
   The thread id is generated with corresponding sender-receiver pair from the client side. The table 'messenger_threads' is populated with the generated thread id. If the conversation with the same sender receiver pair is in the table, no insertion is done.

Likewise the participants in group and private chat for the same thread_id (conservation id) is populated in the table 'messenger_participants'

In table 'messenger_messages', the new messages are inserted with the thread_id, message body and sender id(which is the user_id in the table)
So in a particular conversation/thread (either a group or private chat)
all messages and sender details are available.

In the table 'user_messages', the message id and the associated users details(both sender and receivers) is updated, so that the message cleared action of every user can be updated.

The user id details are retrieved from table 'users' table

**Users**
Attributes
1.id
2.username
3.other_details..

Could you please assist me in the query for retrieving the all the conversations of a single user with the latest message information like facebook messenger.Also give me suggestions in the db design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select mthread.subject subject,message.last_message 
from messenger_threads mthread,
    (select mm.thread_id thread_id,mm.body last_message,max(mm.updated_at) max_date 
            from messenger_messages mm 
                group by mm.thread_id) message
where mthread.id in 
    (select thread_id from messenger_participants mpart where user_id in(?)) 
    and message.thread_id=mthread.id 
order by mthread.updated_at desc;
```

This query should serve the purpose you need, provided performance tuning could be applied on this to improve it further. Suggestions to improve this query is welcome.